# xlwings 0.23.2 - Run-time error '53': File not found

Tags: python, xlwings

I changed my conda system from anaconda to miniconda. Everything was working normally with anaconda but after the change xlwings stopped working.

Now I am getting the following error `Run-time error '53': File not found`.

On debugging through the VBA interface, I found that the routine was searching in the folder `C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\LocalTemp\` (not the project's folder) and coming up with a very long .log filename which changes each time I attempt to run it (eg. `xlwings-374ABEE7-4C51-8622-AB5B-D42C5294C2B8.log`)

Is this a bug which needs to be corrected? or have I done something incorrectly?

> System: Windows 10; MS Office 365; xlwings ver: 0.23.2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had a similar issue that drove me crazy.
After hours of debug and testing, I randomly click on the RunPython: Use UDF server checkbox and it worked